# Allow users to mark or flag an item that its has been opened/read - SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, power-automate, flow, json-formatting

I have got several lists and I would like to have a flag that users can use e.g yes/no to say they have read the content or not.

Any ideas or resources would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: check this column formatting sample I have submitted: https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/tree/master/column-samples/generic-like-unlike. Let me know if this works for your scenario.

Comment: Thanks Ganesh.
I believe this is using SetValue(CustomRowAction).Does this actually update a field in the list?

Comment: Yes, it updates the actual value in the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your requirements using JSON formatting in SharePoint online lists.

Create a multiple selection person or group column to store the user names who voted yes/no on list item.

You can create buttons using JSON formatting to update person or group column based on user selection. You have to use `SetValue` action to update column values.

Check below list formatting sample I submitted for similar idea: [Like/Unlike List Item](https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/tree/master/column-samples/generic-like-unlike)

[image]